# how to redirect to email address when ckick on email address through java script?

Tags: javascript, email

i wanted to redirect the email  when i m click on the email address which provide by user...
hep me....

what m i done....

```
 <li onClick="madd(this)" data-ajax="false">mahesh.magdum@gmail.com</li>
```

javascript code is....

```
  function madd(add)
{
    var address="";
    var address=$(add).text();
    alert(address);
    window.location.href=address;
}
```

but it just try to find the page named as mahesh.magdum@gmail.com
....
so what can i do????????

Comment: Prefix with `mailto:`

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you need to send an email to this address (`mailto:mahesh.magdum@gmail.com`), or to redirect to some page called `http://example.com/mahesh.magdum@gmail.com` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href="mailto:mahesh.magdum@gmail.com" data-ajax="false">mahesh.magdum@gmail.com</a>
```

Comment: No javascript is required. Only this will work. Just replace you html with the above line. Do if any html changes required. And you should be done.

Comment: there is one problem...output is that action is not currently supported..what can i do???

Comment: Please post your changed html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean :

```
<a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com">Send</a>
```

Comment: yes...it will be redirect to my account n in sender list id will be mahesh.magdum@gmail.com

Comment: i tried it...there is on eproblem...action is not currently supported...what can i do??? hav to import some file????

Comment: Could you give more details about your needs.
Simply send an email or anything else ?

Comment: hey u r ri8..i was triying it in emmulator so it was not working... but in browser its work..thanx again...